# Efficient structure for Multiple Thread access

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, performance

I need to implement a mechanism which has a datastruture (Queue at this moment) that contains a list of pending request objects which are marked by different threads when being used and taken off when a thread is finished using it.

This datastructure could have up to a few thousand items in it at any given time and N threads will be taking requests from it (essentially marking it as 'taken') then when the thread is finished it will find that same request in the structure and remove it.

Now I was wondering how effective a C++ STL Queue would be in terms of doing this, and in terms of having to look for the same item again when needing to remove it from the queue?

I don't want this datastructure to be locked by a Thread Synchronization mechanisms for too long because a thread is looking for an items somewhere within it.  This could lock up my entire program.  (The program needs to be very high performance and fast)

Can anyone advice on how to best implement this in a multi-threading environment so that the structure doesn't get locked up for long times when a search needs to be performed?

Comment: is there a reason you cannot take the items from the queue immediately instead of marking them first? that would be faster for sure.

Comment: Any reason to keep the request in the queue after it is 'taken'? It would become so much easier (faster) when you can simply remove the item and process it.

Comment: Yes but then I'd need a way to keep track of the item that has been taken off the queue for logging purposes, etc.  Want to keep track of which thread took what item off the queue.  Putting it on another queue makes it too complicated, is what I thought.

Comment: just holding the item in the queue for logging purposes sounds weird. Can't the thread that took the item do the logging?

Comment: I guess I can do the logging in the consumer thread, but there's also the matter of request timeout, how would you implement a timeout mechanism if you don't have an overall way to check how long a request has been running?  Per thread seems a bit overly complex I think?

Answer (score 1):

You may be focusing on what is not the hardest part of your design here.

If the queue is FIFO without any prioritization then your accessors are going to be push_back() and pop_front() - very fast even if you don't go to the trouble of using compare-and-swap (CAS) semantics but stick with a simple mutex/critical section.  If you need the ability to prioritize traffic then things get harder.  If you do use CAS locking then (on Windows anyway) you cannot improve on boost::thread's shared_mutex without spending way too much time doing this part of your coding.  Not sure about the non-Windows implementations.

The more complex part of this problem is typically signalling idle worker threads to pick up new work.  You can't have them looping until queue.front() is non-empty so you need a way to ensure the correct number of idle threads get kicked to pick up queued items.  When a worker thread goes idle it can check for new work and execute if so, if not then the queue state needs to be set to idle so that the next push_back results in a "wake up" kick to restart the worker thread pool. This area has to be 100% robust to all non-fatal exceptions or your process will go dark.

Are you managing your own threads or using a built-in thread pool?  Are you planning to have a dynamically-sized thread pool or just spawn N threads (configurable presumably) and have them run until process exit?

Definitely have the worker threads do the logging of work item process.  Understanding who owns a workitem at any part of its lifecycle is vital.  Stop/start work, and a workitem summary and timing is going to be useful.  if logging is slow then push this off to a separate thread via a fire-and-forget queue but then you have to look out for latency there making your log less useful.  If you do need the ability to externally manipulate in-progress workitems then a separate structure from your queue of pending work - in-progress work items indexed by thread and showing current status/start time, with separate locking, sounds like a good idea.  This structure is going to be O(thread count) so smaller than the "pending" queue so scanning it is not likely to be a bottleneck provided long-running resultant ops are done outside the structure lock.

Regarding performance - what are your worker threads going to be doing?  if work items are going to be long-running, do a lot of I/O or other expensive operations, then the queue interaction is not your performance bottleneck anyway so over-optimizing that area is relatively unproductive.  Consider perf of the entire system in your design, not just one small area.

This is just for starters. Good luck, this is not an easy system to design robustly.

[EDIT] based on workitem description.

Parsing should be quick (although may involve costly source data retrieval - hard to say?), DB access less so. Sounds like tuning the DB may be your biggest bang per buck perf-wise.  If you don't have control of this then you just have to mitigate slow DB in your design as much as possible. If you have the option to do async DB access then the worker thread could just do enough work to kick off the DB call and then complete the work on a callback, allowing other work to get kicked off on the worker thread. Without async DB access, reliable request timeout will be hard to implement without some alternative method of indirection where your main worker thread does not wait for the DB calls to complete inline.  You need to decouple your main worker threads from reliance on the DB unless you can trust the DB to return or error out in a timely way.  Maybe some configurable or workitem-specific timeout on the DB request?  Often the DB API libraries allow this.

Your timeout monitor would need to stay aware of the workitem state. Possibly some virtual Cancel() method on your workitem, to ensure flexibility in cleanup of timed-out items.

Comment: thanks for your input; the worker threads are going to be parsing scripts(VBScript, Python, Jscript), getting data from an oracle database.

Comment: The number of threads will be configurable, so not really a pool.

Comment: There is also COM Calls made to another DLL, will a thread block on a COM Call? That DLL actually does most of the I/O, db accesses, so if I wait on a COM call, could I do an async notify when the DLL has finished and meanwhile my worker can process something else?

Comment: Then IF you have control of the COM DLL, that is the interface where I would split off the worker thread from "stuff that could go wrong".  If you can implement a completion callback from the COM DLL to your own code then you have separated your code from the long-running stuff that is outside its control.  For sure your worker thread can then do other stuff, and process state change for COM completions as they arrive. Cancellation is then a matter of maybe issuing a second COM call to cancel the remote work, and cleaning up local state so that an inflight or late-arriving callback is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting](http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/208801371) Herb Sutter:

> Linked lists are wonderfully
>   concurrency-friendly data structures
>   because they support highly localized
>   updates. In particular, as illustrated
>   in Figure 1, to insert a new node into
>   a doubly linked list, you only need to
>   touch two existing nodes; namely, the
>   ones immediately adjacent to the
>   position the new node will occupy to
>   splice the new node into the list. To
>   erase a node, you only need to touch
>   three nodes: the one that is being
>   erased, and its two immediately
>   adjacent nodes.

That aside, I agree with the comments that you should probably remove the item from the queue before processing it. But I may be wrong as I don't know the finer details of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a long look at Herb Sutters "[Effective Concurrency](http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/200001985;jsessionid=H42O1W2AQAFLPQE1GHPCKHWATMY32JVN)" series (soon to be a book).

Always remove items from the queue before consuming - you don't eat apples while still on the tree do you?

In short: When removing stuff from the queue/singly-linked-list use a compare-and-swap atomic operation or in Windows parlance [InterlockedExchangePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683609%28VS.85%29.aspx). This will always allow one thread to be moving forward. There are probably similar functions in Boost.

Also move the logging into the class doing the consuming.